# Dynamic Banners on Websites

Tags: website-design, graphic-design

Often on webpages, you see scrolling banners with messages. I would like to know how these are created. To make my question more clear, consider this webpage: http://www.ecs.soton.ac.uk.

On the top, you see a dynamic banner with changing images and messages. How are these done? I use Dreamweaver, so any information with respect to this software would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to UX.  Unfortunately your question isn't about UX, but about the tools used in graphic design.  It may be better to post it in the Graphic Design StackExchange site.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to web design and hence a bit shky with respect to terminology. Thanks, for pointing it out to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called a slider or carousel.

it can be done with Javascript/jquery (mostly done by huge websites/companies) and it also can be done with css look at littleyang's answer about twitter bootstrap carousel.

a few links of great working javascript/jquery sliders:

http://www.progressivered.com/cu3er/

http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding

http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/

http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Write some js method to do this,Jquery can easily to get it. Or bootstrap also can do it.
here is the link for bootstarp
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Comment: Thank you. I am looking forward to learning web coding. Thank you for the link.